# Submiting my form to a ajax script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I submit my form so that it goes through the ajax script to insert the data rather than the PHP script. When I submit the form now it goes to the PHP script. I want it to stay on the same page. I have jquery installed and the ajax script in the proper place.

```
<form action="addsigningfee.php"  method="post">     
<input name="signingfee" type="text">
<input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pid ; ?>">
<p></p>
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>  


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "addsigningfee.php",
            data: $("FORM").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("It worked!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

addsigningfee.php

```
<?php
        require_once("connect.php");

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO options(signingfee,pid)values(?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['signingfee'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['pid'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();

?>
```

Comment: what is the contents of addsigningfee.php? also your jQuery should have an onsubmit as currently it wont get called by any action

Comment: what is "ajax script"?

Comment: the content of the addsigningfee.php is at the bottom of my question. Where should I add the onsubmit.

Comment: The Ajax script is the JavaScript it is the script on my question that starts with <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="myForm" action=""  method="post">     
    <input name="signingfee" type="text">
    <input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pid ; ?>">
    <p></p>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit','form.myForm',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "addsigningfee.php",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("It worked!");
            }
        });
       return false; 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to prevent the form's default action `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the page from posting and reloading...

Comment: OK I changed everything to look like your suggestion. It did not add any data to the database. The PHP script works if I send data directly to it from the form.

Comment: @War10ck added code to prevent form being submitted

Comment: @Richard corrected the Javascript, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Make `addsigningfee.php` a standalone file like this:

```
<?php

    require_once("connect.php");

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO options(signingfee,pid)values(?,?)");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['signingfee'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 250);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['pid'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

and your other page `example.html` this:

```
<form action="addsigningfee.php"  method="post">     
<input name="signingfee" type="text">
<input name="pid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pid ; ?>">
<p></p>
<button id="form-submit" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>  


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#form-submit').click(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();

           $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "addsigningfee.php",
                data: $("FORM").serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    alert("It worked!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your script tag with this:

```
<script>
    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('form').prop('action'),
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                console.log("BAM!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Don't forget to prevent the form's default action `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the page from posting and reloading...

Comment: Question how does your script know what form is sending data to it. I have about fifty forms or more in this program.

Comment: there is six forms on this one page

Comment: @War10ck Thanks! Forgot that.

Comment: @RichardKurth Then just give your form a name or id and reference it by that, e.g. `<form id="awesomeform"></form>` and then you would get the URL with `$('#awesomeform).prop('action')`

Comment: what should the form look like  this is what I have but it seams to bypass js and it runs the php script                                <form id="signingfee" action="addsigningfee.php"  method="post">     
    <input name="signingfee" type="text">
    <input name="pid" type="hidden" value="7">
    <p></p>
    <button id="mySubBtn" type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<button id="mySubBtn" type="submit">Save</button>

$("#mySubBtn").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "addsigningfee.php",
            data: $("FORM").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("It worked!");
            }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false;` should be outside the AJAX call after the ajax's `});`. Otherwise, while the page will submit while the AJAX call is pending. Also, try using `event.preventDefault();` as it is preferred over `return false;`.

Comment: I used your script and the form sent the data directly to the PHP script

Answer (score -1):

Currently your code is firing the AJAX call on `DocumentContentLoaded` rather than on form submit.

Target the form's `submit` event, prevent the default submit action and then fire the AJAX call. Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').on('submit', function (evt) {
        // Prevent the page from reloading (default action of a form submit)
        evt.preventDefault();

        // Fire the AJAX call to your server
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "addsigningfee.php",
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert("It worked!");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Reference Documentation:**

[`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Note that `.submit()` is shorthand for `.on('submit' ...)`